# Can I get a 200mH inductor off the shelf that I can connect across AC mains?

Tags: power-factor-correction

I am designing an automatic power factor correction system, for testing I want an inductive load. I want to use a pure inductor placed in series with a resistor, I have read of inductive load banks but they are just too expensive for my project.

Comment: What current do you expect it to carry?

Comment: What value of resistance and what space limitations do you have because if R is low then the inductor will be big. What AC voltage and frequency are you talking about? No, it won't be off the shelf and no, this site isn't a shopping site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Dirk Buere, It is around 2-3 Amps,in any case what i am really concerned with is if the inductor can withstand 220V AC mains, even if the current is small i can still manipulate it because i am using a current transformer to tap the current signal.

Comment: @Andy aka,I want to connect the inductor across 220 Volts AC mains in series with a 25 ohm resistor, at 50 Hertz frequency. If it wont be off the shelf, how best can i get one. The main objective is to have the current lag the voltage with a considerable phase, 45-70 degrees, how best can i achieve it.

Comment: Digikey is perfectly willing to sell you a 200 mA, 2 A inductor with a 1.7 ohm resistance for 60 dollars. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/71?k=&pkeyword=&pv19=578&FV=ffe00047&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that the inductor core will be silicon steel laminate you can find two things from the internet: -

- The relative magnetic permeability is about 4000 and
- The maximum flux density is about 1 tesla for decent inductor operation.

[image]

From this you can calculate the maximum H-field applied to the core that you can tolerate before exceeding the maximum flux density. It's simply a case of converting relative to absolute permeability and dividing this into 1 tesla.

I get a peak H field of 198.9 ampere turns per metre. It pretty much "aligns" with the above graph for silicon steel.

The "per metre" part is the overall mean length of the core: -

[image]

Knowing the inductance, frequency and applied voltage you can now calculate the peak current. If I assume 220 volts RMS and 50 Hz, the peak current is 4.952 amps.

Given that you have previously calculated the peak H-field you can divide this by peak current to get "turns per metre" (about 40.2 turns for a 1 metre core length).

Now the inductance formula: -

[image]

- A = cross sectional area of core and
- l is the mean length of the core.
- N is number of turns.

If you substitute N/l with H and then divide by the peak current you get: -

\$L = \dfrac{\mu N HA}{I}\$

And, if you plug the numbers in for the known values you get \$AN\$ = 1. This means that for 40 turns, A = 0.025 sq metres and of course this is a very fat core of cross section 158 mm x 158 mm. Additionally, the core length needs to be 1 metre long.

If you were expecting some inch cube or smaller inductor then I hope you can see why it needs to be many times this size. The only possibility of reducing the core size is to gap the core. Gapping the core means the effective permeability drops and you can tolerate a bigger H field. To restore the inductance you have to increase the number of turns of course.

If the effective permeability dropped by 4 (due to gapping), the number of turns would have to double to restore the inductance (because inductance is proportional to turns squared). Now we need 80.4 turns and our peak H-field can now be as high as 795.8 At/m (to produce 1 telsa in the core).

Based on that H-field, the turns per metre is 160.8 or, putting it another way, the length of the core can now be 0.5 metres - this gives us 80.4 turns.

Plugging these into the formula for inductance and re-arranging, the cross sectional area halves from the previous 0.025 sq m to 0.125 sq m. That's 112 mm x 112 mm and a tad more reasonable.

You could keep going with this - making the gap a bit bigger, reducing the effective permeability, increasing the number of turns to restore the inductance but you will get to a point where you have too many turns and your basic \$I^2R\$ losses become too great.

So, apologies for thinking you could get away with an ungapped core (you can but it will be very big) and good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot @ Andy aka, will give you feedback on how far i have gone

Comment: @MajorBeey I've made somewhat of a mistake in this answer so watch out for amendments. Bottom line is that you will need to have a gapped core and many times the number of turns that I've indicated.

Comment: @MajorBeey if this answer helps and you have no further questions please consider formally accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

200mH @ 50Hz presents an impedance of about 60 Ohms. If you connected directly across 220VAC mains you will get a current of about 3.6 Amps.

That in itself will cause no heating. However, the coil resistance will, so you need to take into account I^2 * R, where I=3.6 and R is the resistance in Ohms. Ideally you need less than one Ohm or it will get too hot.

Comment: Thank you for that, my problem is weather that kind of an inductor exists, like to say can i find it from a shop or i will have to dismantle a motor or something?

Comment: *" I=3.6"*  No.  The units of I are not dimensionless.

Comment: It's not sufficient to say use a a coil with less than 1 ohm; you need to choose a coil whose core is big enough to control the peak flux density in order to avoid core saturation. This is the major problem.

Comment: @MajorBeey Not sure. I can guarantee it is going to be BIG - not something you can casually solder to a PCB